# Using pg_dump on a view always produces an empty file

Tags: postgresql, view, export

I want to export a subset of a tables rows using pg_dump (using powershell on windows). The simplest way seems to be to create a view with an appropriate WHERE clause. However, when I run pg_dump on the view the resulting output files never has data in it (it has several rows of SET statements, but no actual data.)

I can successfully run pg_dump on tables without any problems, and creating an appropriate view isn't a problem, I can select from the view using the same account that I'm running pg_dump from so I don't think permissions are an issue. pg_dump isn't producing any errors.

I've been using this command to create the view...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW viewA 
AS
(
  select * from tableA
  WHERE blah blah blah....
);
```

And this command to do the dump

```
$env:PGPASSWORD='own'
.\pg_dump.exe -U myuser -d mydatabase -t viewA -f mydumpfile
```

This works (i.e. it runs without error) but *mydumpfile* never contains data.

If I do something very similar, but creating a table instead....

```
CREATE TABLE tabB 
AS
(
  select * from tableA
  WHERE blah blah blah....
);
```

Followed by an almost identical pg_dump on the *table*...

```
$env:PGPASSWORD='own'
.\pg_dump.exe -U myuser -d mydatabase -t tabB-f mydumpfile
```

Then I get a dump file with the correct data.

Is there any way of using pg_dump against a view. The postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) suggests it should be possible

Comment: If you dump a view, the _definition_ of the view is dumped, not its content. You can use `\copy` to export the data of the view

Comment: The view doesn't contain any data, it is base on the table

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way of using pg_dump against a view. The postgres
> [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) suggests it should be possible

This is not an answer to your question per-se, but the PostgreSQL documentation is certainly very ambiguous there, so I [submitted a patch](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=1b22224945e1e7162fe92aecb1cd2b373fba24c2) to clarify what will be dumped (in particular, only the *definitions* of views), which has been accepted and will be reflected in the current documentation soon.

As mentioned in the comments, the only way to extract the data generated by a view is via psql's `\copy` command, or possibly the `COPY` command itself.